# Creating a compound iterator in F#

Tags: f#, iterator, yield, c#-to-f#, lazy-sequences

I'm implementing a checkers-like game, and I need a sequence that enumerates all legal moves for a given configuration.

I've got the following function, directly translated from C#:

```
seq {
    for y1 = 0 to BOARDSIZE-1 do
        for x1 = 0 to BOARDSIZE-1 do
             for dy = -2 to 2 do
                 for dx = -2 to 2 do
                     let x2 = x1 + dx;
                     let y2 = y1 + dy;
                     let currentMove = new MoveStruct(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                     if (currentMove.SomeCondition = true) then
                             yield currentMove;
   }
```

It works, but it's awkward, and not quite the "F# way", let alone I have a sneaking suspicion that what I'm doing here is not performance optimal.

What I would like is to "flatten this out" into something that uses a combination of "iterate over all cells", "iterate over all valid moves from this cell".

And here are the functions I'm hoping to combine:

```
let AllCells =
    seq {
        for y=0 to BOARDSIZE-1 do
            for x=0 to BOARDSIZE-1 do
                yield (x,y);
    };
```

AND

```
let LegalMovesAround(x1,y1) = 
    seq {
      if board.[x1, y1] = WHITE then
        for dy = -2 to 2 do
          for dx = -2 to 2 do
                let x2 = x1 + dx;
                let y2 = y1 + dy;
                let currentMove = new MoveStruct(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                if (currentMove.DetermineMoveType <> MoveType.ILLEGAL 
                    && board.[x2, y2] = NONE) then
                        yield currentMove;
     }
```

I'm going to spare you the details of my various attempts to make it work, because none of them were successful. But to make the long story short, the best I could come up with is an iterator that returns a seq with each yield, instead of the flattened version I'm looking for, which would return a simple MoveStruct.

Anyone have a good idea how to combine AllCells, and LegalMovesAround(x,y)?

Regards,
Aleks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to combine them the way they are and then flatten, something like this:

```
 let validMoves = 
    AllCells 
    |> Seq.collect LegalMovesAround
    |> Seq.distinct
```

It may not be the best solution performance-wise though.

EDIT: Fixed sample code as per Tomas comment

Comment: Beware of mixing lazy sequences and side effects! If the board is mutated, it's important to have a clear understanding of when the entire sequence is evaluated. Calling Seq.distinct looks dangerous here.

Comment: Never mind my comment above, Seq.distinct would be called before going down the moves tree.

Comment: This doesn't type check. I guess `legalMovesAround` should be argument of `Seq.collect`.

Comment: @Tomas: I should really not write answers without having FSI around. :)

Comment: Thanks, JUST the solution I was looking for. Short, to the point and no for loops :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use yield! in a new sequence expression:

```
let allLegalMoves = seq {
  for cell in AllCells do
    yield! LegalMovesAround cell
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of `yield!`?

something like

```
seq {
    for x,y in Allcells do
        yield! LMA(x,y)
}
```

Comment: This solution also works, except it returns a sequence with each yield, while I prefer it to return a MoveStruct. The caller shouldn't need to know about the details of the implementation.

Comment: No, it yields a MoveStruct.  Try it.